# Openldap: access to attribute of subtree

Tags: ldap, openldap

As shown in [documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) (article 8.2.5) I'm trying to restrict access to attributes of `dn.subtree="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local"` for `dn="cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local"`, but there is no access to specified attributes for `dn="cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local"`

```
root@metalmachine:~# ldapsearch -D "cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" -W -b "ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local" mail
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
# 
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: mail
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Here is two access directives for `dn.subtree="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local"`

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local" attrs=uid,mail,cn,gn,sn,displayName
        by dn="cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" read
        by dn="cn=dovecot,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" read

access to dn.subtree="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local"
        by dn="cn=dovecot,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" read
        by anonymous auth
        by self read
        by * none
```

Everything works fine for `dn="cn=dovecot,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
access to dn.children="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local" attrs=uid,mail,cn,gn,sn,displayName
        by dn="cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" read

access to dn.subtree="ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local"
        by dn="cn=addrbook,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" search
        by dn="cn=dovecot,ou=services,dc=domain,dc=local" read
        by anonymous auth
        by self read
        by * none
```